# PowerShell: Redirecting mysqldump.exe's errors

Tags: powershell, error-handling, mysql

Here is the command I have been using to back up one of my MySQL databases:

```
mysqldump.exe --user=myuser --password=mypassword --databases --opt MyDatabase > "C:\MyDatabase.sql"
```

I'd like to use this command in a PowerShell script. However, if an error occurs, I don't want it to be outputted to the console. Instead, I would like it captured in a variable. I've been trying various methods of doing this, but all have failed. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, beware `>` if your database dump does not need to be in Unicode, but rather ASCII. You would instead use `| out-file $filepath -enc ascii` to make sure it writes in ASCII encoding. *(My databases are in latin1. If I use Powershell's `>` the dump file is twice as large as when dumped using `>` from normal console.)*

That said, I got it to dump to a file in ASCII format and put the errors in a variable in this way (forcing an error by trying to dump a nonexistent database, but mysqldump outputs a number of initializing lines of the dump before it throws the error):

```
$err = (mysqldump -uroot -p --databases nonexistent | out-file C:\backup.sql -enc ascii) 2>&1
```

This wraps the execution so that stdout is piped to `out-file`, but after that wrapping, stderr is redirected to stdout so that it can be assigned to variable $err.

`$err` is 1 `ErrorRecord` or more. A single error has a `TargetObject` property containing the original stderr output. Here's a demo of printing every error string to the console:

```
if ($err -is [system.array]) {
    $err | % { write-host $_.TargetObject }
} else {
    write-host $err.TargetObject
}
```

Alternately, you can ensure that `$err` is an array by slightly modifying the original dump statement by wrapping it an `@()` (*good idea, Mike*):

```
$err = @((mysqldump -uroot -p --databases nonexistent | out-file C:\backup.sql -enc ascii) 2>&1)
```

Comment: Couldn't you use @( ) instead of $( ) to make $err be an array?  That would eliminate the need for if/else.

Comment: Thank you very much! I replaced `$(mysqldump...` with `$(& "$MySQLDumpPath"...` and that did the trick.

Comment: @Frank: Sure. I can call mine very simply like I did because MySQL's `bin` path is part of my `PATH` environment variable. You can also put your entire call in a string variable like `$mdump = "$MySQLDumpPath --arg1 --arg2"` and execute it with `iex $mdump`.

Comment: @Mike: When I do that in my test, `$err` still isn't an array. You'd have to do it like this, I think: `$err = @((mysqldump ... | out-file ...) 2>&1)`. The `@()` needs to be around the entire thing.